# Could not set 'present' on ensure: No such file or directory

Tags: unix, manifest, puppet, puppet-enterprise

Getting the error below on the agent side when I try to sign the certificate and test it.

```
Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: No such file or directory - /usr/local/sbin/logbackup.sh20151015-45265-ouqjrt.lock at 2:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/logbackup/manifests/init.pp
Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: No such file or directory - /usr/local/sbin/logbackup.sh20151015-45265-ouqjrt.lock at 2:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/logbackup/manifests/init.pp
Wrapped exception:
No such file or directory - /usr/local/sbin/logbackup.sh20151015-45265-ouqjrt.lock
Error: /Stage[main]/Logbackup/File[/usr/local/sbin/logbackup.sh]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Could not set 'present' on ensure: No such file or directory - /usr/local/sbin/logbackup.sh20151015-45265-ouqjrt.lock at 2:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/logbackup/manifests/init.pp
```

Comment: That appears to be a problem in a third-party module named "logbackup".  I cannot say whether it might be related to some other issue, whether you're using it wrong, or whether it's just broken.  Certainly, though, the error messages suggest some very surprising behavior, so I'm inclined to suspect that the module is flawed.  Getting to this point probably means that your agent successfully received its signed certificate, though.

Comment: Turns out I had to create the directory sbin manually. It's strange as it should be made by puppet automatically(and it did with other servers but not this one).

Comment: Puppet manages only those files (directories) it is told to manage.  It does not automatically create directories in the path to a managed file except when they are managed as their own, separate resources.

Comment: Every time I installed and configured it, it created "/usr/local/sbin" in all other servers. This server was the only exception.

Comment: Check rights on folders in /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/logbackup/ on puppetmaster. They should belong to user, from which puppetmaster is running

Comment: Working after manually adding the directory "sbin".